# How to send ||= in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model that I want to assign default values to from passed hash

```
def assign_defaults(attr={})
   self.attributes.keys.each do |x|
      send("#{x} ||=", attr[x])
   end
end
```

But it raises an exception: `undefined method 'id ||=' for #<Model..>`

I've also tried `send("#{x}.||=", attr[x])`, doens't work either

Comment: why not just `attributes[x] ||= attr[x]` not need for send since you clearly have access to attributes or better yet `self.attributes.merge! {|_key,old,_new| old }` seems like both would have the same effect and the second would not need to loop through all attributes where `attr[x]` was none existent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby, `||=` is a keyword, not a method. Thus you can't send it to objects.

In Rails, you can access model attributes using bracket notation, so you could write your code:

```
def assign_defaults(attr = {})
  self.attributes.keys.each do |x|
    self[x] ||= attr[x]
  end
end
```

Comment: That makes so much sense. I don't know what I was thinking

Comment: Actually may not be so obvious, because Ruby (and OOP in general) is all about message passing, and Ruby also has setter methods, which sort of look like assignment. :-)